# WPF dependency between controls

Tags: wpf, checkbox, textbox, isenabled

I have 3 textboxes their visibility depends on checkbox. I want to set IsEnabled = false on all textboxes, when checkbox.IsChecked = false and IsEnabled = true when IsChecked=true. How can I achieve this dependency in XAML?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind between named elements, and as long as you are binding to dependency properties, the binding will reflect any changes

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `IsEnabled` property to the `IsChecked` property on the `CheckBox`.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=NameOfCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

If your goal is to then tie that bool value to `Visibility` as your question suggests, you would then need to also leverage a converter, such as the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=NameOfCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Name="Checker" />

    <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Checker, Path=IsChecked}" />
    <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Checker, Path=IsChecked}" />
    <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Checker, Path=IsChecked}" />
</StackPanel>
```